# How to do a record certificates application in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I need to design a program that stores data from which you can request a student's attendance, grades, and student's regularity. Without using Databases on Visual Basic 6. There must be at least 3 students to request data from. I'd appreciate any help because I'm kind of new to VB6.

Comment: are you **sure** you are using VB6 and not VB.NET?  this sounds like homework and VB6 is 17 years old.  regardless, SO requires much more focused questions

Comment: Im 100% sure, It's VB6 and not VB.net. That's why I'm asking for help and I dont find much resources for this, Im studying computer science at a college that seems to like reviewing ancient software so... What do you mean by SO requires much more focused questions?

Comment: SO (StackOverflow) is for answering programming questions not overall general design questions.  3 people could give 9 different answers to an overly broad question like this one.

Comment: How on earth do you get a homework assignment in (a long dead language) VB6?  Bad teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the information in flat files and comma separate the values on each line to represent columns in a database.
Have a look here http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/29575-file-handling-in-visual-basic-6-part-1-sequential-files/

It's not too difficult. I didn't find your question too general at all.